# istockphoto for videos

Tags: video

I am thinking about make some story video and I would leverage some general footage -- timelapses, cars passing streets, etc. Is there some service which provides such assets? I think I saw something like "video building block" service or something like that. I don't need this service specifically, but just something where could I download/buy such video assets shoot by somebody else.

Comment: All the replies are cool. Which should I mark as the correct answer?! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used the following services:

[Video Blocks](https://www.videoblocks.com) - perhaps this is the one you were thinking of?

[iStockPhoto](http://www.istockphoto.com)

[ShutterStock](http://www.shutterstock.com)

Answer (score 1):

- http://www.gettyimages.de/footage
- https://www.shutterstock.com/video/
- http://www.dissolve.com/
- http://videohive.net/

to name a few, probably there are much much more.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think your best source to tell stories with would be public domain videoes.

Either videos placed directly into the public domain or those whose copyright has expired and are now in the public domain

see (a good resource):

http://www.pond5.com/free

For example, the charlie chaplin videos, all the silent movies, unfortunately all movies including the 70's should have been in the public domain by now if it wasn't for the walt disney copyright extension law. Oh well, we take things as they are. Lots of great resources to be found in the public domain.

other sites:

(Public domain films)
https://www.loc.gov/rr/mopic/pubdomain.html

https://archive.org/details/stock_footage